# Motivation for Non-Euclidean geometry: relativity

Tags: geometry, riemannian-geometry, education, general-relativity

I'm looking for references to motivate the study of non-Euclidean geometry. In particular I would like something about relativity.

I do not want texts to learn non-Euclidean geometry, only motivational documents for a class.

I've seen some questions on this page but they relate more to full texts about relativity or non-Euclidean geometry.

I appreciate what you can recommend me.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_general_relativity lists the key concepts

Comment: A non-relativity motivation for non-Euclidean geometry is the big blue round thingy we live on.

Comment: Also see [What is the relationship between hyperbolic geometry and Einstein's special relativity?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/497504/35416) By the way, do you want *general* or *special* relativity? One of your tags suggests the former, but the latter might be easier for class. So perhaps you should address that distinction in your question text, to state whether or not you prefer one over the other.

Comment: If you want to motivate non-Euclidean geometry for non-mathematicians, you could try [M.C. Escher](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~mec/Winter2009/Mihai/section2.html) and such as how he moved from plane tessellation in [Angel-Devil](http://www.mcescher.com/gallery/paint/no-45-angel-devil/) to [Circle Limit IV](http://euler.slu.edu/escher/index.php/File:Circle-limit-IV.jpg)